# How to return data from a bash shell script subroutine?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Given the following two executable scripts:

```
----- file1.sh

#!/bin/sh
. file2.sh
some_routine data

----- file2.sh

#!/bin/sh
some_routine()
{
    #get the data passed in
    localVar=$1
}
```

I can pass 'data' to a subroutine in another script, but I would also like to return data.

Is it possible to return information from some_routine?

```
e.g: var = some_routine data
```

Comment: Just fyi, you can't have a space in the assignment: `var=$(some_routine data)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have the subroutine output something, and then use `$()` to capture the output:

```
some_routine() {
    echo "foo $1"
}

some_var=$(some_routine bar)
```

Comment: This and other solutions are discussed at http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions

Comment: Thank-you for the responses.  The option provided by Amber works, but not in my case.  My routines echo various status messages and can return an early response.  I tried the second option under the link that jofel provided and it works perfectly for me.  jofel, can you please respond to my question with that answer?  I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not allowed, just set the value of a global variable (..all variables are global in bash)

Answer (score 0):

if

```
some_routine() {
    echo "first"
    echo "foo $1"
}

some_var=$(some_routine "second")
echo "result: $some_var"
```

they are ok.But the result seems to be decided by the first "echo".Another way is use "eval".
some_var return "first"

```
some_routine()
{
        echo "cmj"
        eval $2=$1
}

some_routine "second" some_var
echo "result: $some_var"
```

in this way, some_var return "second".The bash don't return a string directly.So we need some tricks.